# Are people named or called?

Tags: word-choice, differences

This is probably a two part question. Sorry.

I often hear news reporters refer to subjects in their stories as follows: "A baseball player for the Chicago Cubs *called* John Doe..."
It seems a verbose. "John Doe, a Chicago Cubs baseball player..." is more succinct. The verb, "called," is unnecessary, or is there a reason for this construction?

The second question has to do with the use of called versus named. In the sentence below, do *named* and *called* work equally well?

The first president of the United States named George Washington never cut down a cherry tree.

The first president of the United States called George Washington never cut down a cherry tree.

Comment: Many expressions are not technically grammatically necessary but still exist for a variety of reasons. Also, your two alternatives are not exactly equivalent. The first version emphasizes the fact that he is a Cubs player (in this case it happens to be John Doe), and the second version emphasizes the fact that he is John Doe (who happens to also be a Cubs player).

Answer (score 1):

People are both named and called. You are "named" at birth by your parents, and "called" by other people during your lifetime.

In your examples, however, I would use neither verb.

**"The first president of the United States, George Washington, never cut down a cherry tree."**

That does not mean those verbs do not have their uses, however. Sometimes it improves the flow of a sentence or changes the emphasis to use "named" or "called" instead of an appositive.

"I saw a baseball player named Joe Jackson."

"I saw a baseball player called Shoeless Joe."

"I saw a baseball player, Shoeless Joe Jackson."